# ShortInteger invalid data type SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

As I'm trying to create this table in SQL Developer

```
CREATE TABLE CARTECREDIT 
(
    forfaitID  INTEGER,
    nomForfait VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL ,
    cout NUMBER(10,4),
    locationMax SHORTINTEGER  NOT NULL,
    dureeMax  SHORTINTEGER   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (forfaitID)
);
```

I'm facing this error message

> Error report -
>   ORA-00902: invalid datatype
>   00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

It seems that SQL Developer is not recognizing the `SHORTINTEGER` as they're not highlighted in blue

But according to the documentation [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm) the `SHORTINTEGER` is a real datatype

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Just a quick comment on using INTEGER, SMALLINT etc. in Oracle. One would think that for data type INTEGER, Oracle will use hardware implementation of integer arithmetic. **It doesn't**. No matter what data type you declare, Oracle will use library functions for all arithmetic, so using INTEGER will actually be inefficient because it will require a cast to NUMBER and then a cast back to INTEGER. This arrangement is very far from optimal (what was Oracle thinking?) but that's where we are. Use `NUMBER(..., 0)` and check constraints if you want to force your data to be integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHORTINTEGER is not supported.
You're linking the docs for datatypes used in OLAP Datawerehouse.

Datatypes for Oracle 10 are specified here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54873

If you want to use Oracle Native datatypes your should use NUMBER (optionally specifying precision and scale) and VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR

You can use, however, ANSI datatypes too, such as INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, VARCHAR. But i suggest you use Oracle native datatypes.

Comment: Thank you ........I guess Oracle is such a big world ..... sorry it's not obvious for someone who haven't experienced all the Oracle structures

Comment: You're welcome..don't be sorry..Oracle is quite big, as you said too and the documentation is like a labyrinth :)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently using number, without specifying precision and scale. And it is much more comfortable to use. But Massimo answer is bullyseye :)